# camel - get jndi registry

Tags: registry, apache-camel, jndi

I'm using apache camel, and I will be needing the jndi registry so that I can bind an object to it.

How do I retrieve a JNDI registry from a RouteBuilder class? Can I also bind using xml?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this for live code or test code? Since, in tests derived from `CamelTestSupport` you have `CamelTestSupport.createRegistry()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do it not within the RouteBuilder but before adding context to the `camelMain`.

```
JndiRegistry registry = new JndiRegistry();
...
registry.bind("myAntFilter", filter);

DefaultCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
camelMain.getCamelContexts().add(context);
```

It is also important to note that you need to have a jndi.properties in your /resources with the following content:

java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.camel.util.jndi.CamelInitialContextFactory

Without this, I'm getting an exception.

Hope it helps people who stumbled on the same problem

Comment: Thanks @yin03 for this.
It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Does `CamelContext.getRegistry()` suit your needs?

```
/**
 * Returns the registry used to lookup components by name and type such as the Spring ApplicationContext,
 * JNDI or the OSGi Service Registry
 *
 * @return the registry
 */
Registry getRegistry();
```

Otherwise, you can bind things (beans, service references, etc) into the registry via `blueprint.xml` or the spring context files located in `META-INF.spring`.

For testing purposes, you have `CamelTestSupport.createRegistry()`.