# Apache Camel routing with recipientList

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel, messenger

I'm trying to route messages dynamically with org.apache.camel.

Here's my code :

```
from("direct:messenger")
            .routeId("messenger-provider")
            .bean(messengerService, "process")
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
            .recipientList(header("access_token")).ignoreInvalidEndpoints()
```

And here's the part of my service class concerned :

```
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("access_token", messengerServiceEndpoint.getEndpointUri()+"?access_token="+accessToken);
```

In fact I want to add the access_token dynamically to the endpoint URI. But i can only get the token from the service class.

If anyone have some insights that would be great, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is **org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry** or **org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry**:

You can bind your objects to the registry and retrieve where you need.

http://camel.apache.org/registry.html

Check this link for creating SimpleRegistry and using in Java DSL:

http://preparationforinterview.com/preparationforinterview/camel-spring-bean-javadsl

Below is a stackoverflow question on creating JNDIRegistry:

[camel - get jndi registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773330/camel-get-jndi-registry?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

If you are using Spring, then you can use ApplicationContextRegistry:

```
ApplicationContextRegistry registry = exchange.getContext().getRegistry(ApplicationContextRegistry.class);
Map<String,Object>map = (Map<String,Object>)registry.lookup("map");
map.put("objectVar", objectVar);
```

Have a map in your Spring config to load the objects:

```
<bean id="map" class="java.util.HashMap"></bean>
```

Retrieve the objects:

```
Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String,Object>)registry.lookup("map");
    Object1 o = (Object1) map.get("objectVar");
```

Comment: Thank you ! Actually I just solved my problem using exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, params);  But i'll look into that if it allows more abstraction

Comment: I think Exchange.HTTP_QUERY suits your case as you just want to set query params..:)